# Probability of succeeding given infinite trials with decreasing probabilities

Tags: probability

### Problem:

What's the probability of succeeding at a task given infinite trials and a probability of success at the $j$th trial $P_j=e^{-j}$

### My attempt:

The quantity I'm trying to evaluate is $\sum^\infty_{j=1}E_j$ where $E_j$ is the probability of eventually succeding at the $j$th trial.

$E_j = F_{1 \rightarrow j-1} P_j$ where $F_{1 \rightarrow j-1}$ is the probability of failing at all trials $1,2,..,j-1$.

We can re-write $E_j$ as $F_{1\rightarrow j-1}(F_j + P_j) - F_{1\rightarrow j-1}(F_j)=F_{1\rightarrow j-1} - F_{1\rightarrow j}$

Now evaluating the quantity $\sum^\infty_{j=1}E_j$

- $j=1$ term: $P_1$
- $j=2$ term: $F_{1\rightarrow 1} - F_{1\rightarrow 2}$
- $j=3$ term: $F_{1\rightarrow 2} - F_{1\rightarrow 3}$
- ..

Looks like all the terms cancel together except for $P_1$ and $F_{1\rightarrow 1}$ which add up to $1$.

### Sanity Check

A simple counter example like $P_j=0$ can show that this can't be true.

### Question

Where did I go wrong with my derivation? Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I missed the last term $-F_{1\rightarrow\infty}$ the answer is $1-F_{1\rightarrow\infty} \approx 0.5$

[wolframalpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=product+of+%281-e%5E-j%29+from+j%3D1+to+j%3D100)